# RadioGroup empty field check using setError in Android

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I was wondering how to `setError` for a `RadioGroup`[gender] with `RadioButton`'s [gender_b,gender_c] if it is null.

This is how i'm getting the `RadioButton` values though:

```
private boolean genradiocheck() {


    boolean gender_flag = false;
    if (gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {



    } else {
        gender_b = (RadioButton) findViewById(gender
                .getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        System.out.println("*********************" + gender_b.getText());
        gender_flag = true;
    }

    return gender_flag;
}
```

Now my question is, how do i put it into a string and check for null values?

This is for a Registration form validation. Thank you.

Answer (score 36):

`setError()` method is not available for `RadioGroup` but you can apply it for `RadioButton`.

Follow these steps:

1. Make `RadioButton` object and initialise it with last item of `RadioGroup`.

   ```
   RadioButton lastRadioBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.lastRadioBtn);
   ```
2. Code below check if `RadioGroup` had been checked and also sets error if not.

   ```
   if(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()<=0){//Grp is your radio group object
       lastRadioBtn.setError("Select Item");//Set error to last Radio button          
   }
   ```

**EDIT:**

If you wish to clear Error:

```
lastRadioBtn.setError(null);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @dgngulcan if you need to clear setError on RadioButton use radioBtn.setError(null), this will remove error

Comment: error mesage not dislpay , can you help me? i just see red error but can not see message

Answer (score 3):

RadioGroup doesn't support setError() method. But we can use setError() on RadioButton.

Get the position of last RadioButton in RadioGroup

```
int lastChildPos=radioGroup.getChildCount()-1;
```

then setError() on radioButton()

```
((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(lastChildPos)).setError("Your error");
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Way to Set Error on TextView Of Radio Group Like Code Bellow
textViewOfRadioGroup.setError("Please Select Item");

After This Set your Text View To Null in OnCheckedChangeListener Like this

textViewOfRadioGroup.setError(null);